# WCF Сервис передача в сервис кнопки

Tags: wcf

Подскажите можно ли написать метод в сервисе, который будет возвращать и принимать не только простые типы, вроде string, int, а более сложные, мне в частности нужно передать кнопку, класс Button. Чтобы сервис не сообщение выводил в клиенте, а кнопку нажимаю и даже передвигал её, то есть менял location у кнопки, как это реализовать и возможно ли это на wcf? Если глобально, мне нужно сделать игру в шашки на wcf, я легко могу передать сообщение в несколько клиентов ,но я не знаю как передать кнопку в несколько клиентов, чтобы я подвинул шашку и она подвинулась у всех клиентов?

Comment: Сделайте модельный класс, описывающий нужные параметры кнопки (например, Location), и передавайте его. Передавать целый Button у вас скорее всего не получится, т. к. он явно не сериализируемый.

Comment: И да, у вас не получится трюк наподобие «подвинул оригинал, и копия у клиента тоже сама по себе подвинулась». Вам придётся рассылать обновления явно, никто за вас это не сделает.

Comment: понял, спасибо, я так и думал, только передавать все параметры у каждой кнопки, мне казалось это слишком сложным, ну и технологии, непросто похоже будет это сделать

Comment: А что тут сложного? Есть изменения — отправьте их. Вам придётся пронумеровать все кнопки, и на стороне клиента искать по номеру. Делов-то!

Comment: А вот такое ещё вопрос на вскидку, как скажите я должен создавать шахматную доску в клиенте или в сервисе, то есть мне кажется, что методы, которые создают доску должны остаться в клиенте, а в сервисе только те методы, которые отвечают за манипулирование шашками?

Comment: Да, конечно. Весь UI принадлежит по идее клиенту, серверу он вообще не нужен. Сервер должен знать лишь модельные вещи: позиции шашек, например.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я конечно ещё не сделал, но уже есть некое понимаем))

Comment: Удачи вам! Рад, что смог помочь.